# Disable sorting in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a common button outside and one `ng-grid`. When I select any one row in `ng-grid` and click the button that is outside, I need to disable sorting in `ng-grid`.

How can achieve this?

Comment: Please, elaborate in more details. If I understood right, yes, it is possible; but, I do not see why you would need to have to select a row for this.

Comment: When I select any row and click the edit button, data in the selected row will be populated in textbox. At this time I want to disable the sorting of ng grid.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to disable sorting in ng-grid
1) Turn off sorting on the entire grid:
  $scope.gridOptions = { data : myData,
                           enableSorting: false};
2)Turn off sorting on a column by column basis:
 columnDefs: [{ field: 'firstName', displayName: 'First Name', width: "*", sortable: false}]